# HTML/CSS table layout issue

Tags: html, css

I'm completely layman in CSS and HTML, but there are tasks and they need to be done. For now, I'm doing what it would be, and then I'll figure out how to do it better. Here, during the execution of the tables, I ran into a bunch of problems, but they were solved, but I was already stuck on this one for a long time. So, I need the selected element (table) in the photo to be at the beginning of the page on the left (under the first one already made), but he doesn’t want to move there, if you can, then explain how to move it correctly, or how best to redo is this task complete?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrgZ0.png)

I provide the code below (P.S. I know that it is terrible, but I am not able to do better yet)

```css
#block1{
    width: 40%;  
    height: 250px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-top: solid 3px;
    float: left;
}
 
#block10{
    width: 20%;
    height: 249px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-top: solid 3px;
    float: left;
}
 
#block11{      
    border-top: solid 3px;
    height: 90px;
}
 
#block12{
    height: 30px;
}
 
#block13{
    height: 129px;
}
 
#block14{
    width: 14%;
    height: 249px;
    border-top: solid 3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
 
#block12, #block11, #block13{
    width: 25%;      
    border-left: solid 3px;
    border-right: solid 3px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    float: left;
}
 
#frst1{
    width: 35%;
    height: 70px;
    border-bottom: solid 3px;
    border-right: solid 3px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15pt;
}
#frst3{
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: solid 3px;
    font-size: 17pt;
}
 
#frst4, #frst2{
    width: 5%;
    border-right: solid 3px;
}
 
#frst4, .scnd2{
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
 
.scnd, .scnd2{
    width: 3%;
    border-right: solid 1px;
    border-left: solid 1px;   
}
 
.frt, .frt1, .frt2{
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
 
.frt1{
    width: 50%;
    border-right: solid 1px;
}
 
.frt2{
    width: 25%;
    border-right: solid 1px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    font-size: 22px;
}
 
 
#block2{
    width:2.5%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
 
    <table id="block1">
 
    <tr>
    <th id = "frst1">Ⅱ. Облік проведення занять та їх <br> відвідування </th> 
    <td id = "frst2"></td>         
    </tr>    
 
    <tr>
    <td id = "frst3">Навчальна дисципліна, <br>викладач, заклад </td>
    <td id="frst4"></td>   
    </tr> 
</table>
<table id= "block10">
 <tr>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th> 
    </tr>     
</table>
 
<table id = "block11" >
    <tr class="frt"> <td> Тиждень №__________</td></tr>
    <tr class="frt"> <td> Пропущ. занять (годин)</td></tr>       
</table>
 
<table id = "block12">
    <tr>
        <td class="frt1">за тиждень</td>   
        <td class="frt1">від початку</td>
   </tr>   
</table>
 
<table id = "block13">
    <tr>
        <td class="frt2">Усього</td>
        <td class="frt2">З непов. причини</td>
        <td class="frt2">Усього</td>
        <td class="frt2">З непов. причини</td>
   </tr>   
</table>
 
 
<table id = "block14">
    <tr>
        <td>Для нотаток</td>
   </tr>   
</table>
 
<table id = "block2">
    <tr><th>№ з/п</th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: First up your HTML is invalid. Don't close your `<br>` tag. It is self-closing. Fix that first. What did you actually try to reposition the element?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, I changed it in the code itself, and threw the old version here. 
I need to do something like this:
https://wiki.cuspu.edu.ua/images/2/20/Table_for_webdev.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add display:block to table 2

```css
#block1{
    width: 40%;  
    height: 250px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-top: solid 3px;
    float: left;
}
 
#block10{
    width: 20%;
    height: 249px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-top: solid 3px;
    float: left;
}
 
#block11{      
    border-top: solid 3px;
    height: 90px;
}
 
#block12{
    height: 30px;
}
 
#block13{
    height: 129px;
}
 
#block14{
    width: 14%;
    height: 249px;
    border-top: solid 3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
 
#block12, #block11, #block13{
    width: 25%;      
    border-left: solid 3px;
    border-right: solid 3px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    float: left;
}
 
#frst1{
    width: 35%;
    height: 70px;
    border-bottom: solid 3px;
    border-right: solid 3px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15pt;
}
#frst3{
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: solid 3px;
    font-size: 17pt;
}
 
#frst4, #frst2{
    width: 5%;
    border-right: solid 3px;
}
 
#frst4, .scnd2{
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
 
.scnd, .scnd2{
    width: 3%;
    border-right: solid 1px;
    border-left: solid 1px;   
}
 
.frt, .frt1, .frt2{
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
 
.frt1{
    width: 50%;
    border-right: solid 1px;
}
 
.frt2{
    width: 25%;
    border-right: solid 1px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    font-size: 22px;
}
 
 
#block2{
    width:2.5%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<table id="block1">
 
    <tr>
    <th id = "frst1">Ⅱ. Облік проведення занять та їх <br> відвідування</br> </th> 
    <td id = "frst2"></td>         
    </tr>    
 
    <tr>
    <td id = "frst3">Навчальна дисципліна, <br>викладач, заклад</br> </td>
    <td id="frst4"></td>   
    </tr> 
</table>
<table id= "block10">
 <tr>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th>
    <th class ="scnd2"></th> 
    </tr>     
</table>
 
<table id = "block11" >
    <tr class="frt"> <td> Тиждень №__________</td></tr>
    <tr class="frt"> <td> Пропущ. занять (годин)</td></tr>       
</table>
 
<table id = "block12">
    <tr>
        <td class="frt1">за тиждень</td>   
        <td class="frt1">від початку</td>
   </tr>   
</table>
 
<table id = "block13">
    <tr>
        <td class="frt2">Усього</td>
        <td class="frt2">З непов. причини</td>
        <td class="frt2">Усього</td>
        <td class="frt2">З непов. причини</td>
   </tr>   
</table>
 
 
<table id = "block14">
    <tr>
        <td>Для нотаток</td>
   </tr>   
</table>
 
<table id = "block2">
    <tr><th>№ з/п</th></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In css of `#block2`, just decrease the `font-size`

```
#block2{
    font-size: 10px;
    width:2.5%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: why would decreasing the font-size matter?

Comment: Sorry but it just changed the font size, it didn't put my table at the top of the page.

Comment: @DCR because the 'width' you applied is giving less space to text.so increase 'width'. If you don't want to decrease font size then remove the "width' property.

Comment: that's just not the problem the op is having.  He wants to move the element to the left.  see accepted answer below

Comment: @DCR Thank you, I made a mistake in understanding the question.